# reducer action is just returning pending promises

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

When I make my http request from my search bar I'm getting this in my console:

[look the image to see my console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tu98.png)

Action received print is a console.log inside the reducer. Request print is a console.log inside the my action after the axios http request. Note that I want that in my reducer I receive the object instead a promise pending. I will put some of code to you guys know the situation and can help me.

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

// const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, createLogger)(createStore);
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware, // lets us dispatch() functions
    loggerMiddleware // neat middleware that logs actions
  )
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

src/actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'MY API KEY'
const API_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${API_URL}&q=${city},BR`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('Request:', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

src/containers/search_bar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(term) {
    this.setState({ term: term });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
    this.setState({ term: '' });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="input-group" onSubmit= { this.onFormSubmit }>
        <input 
          placeholder="Get a five-day forecast in your favorite cities"
          className="form-control"
          value = {this.state.term}
          onChange = { term => this.onInputChange(term.target.value)} 
        />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar)
```

src/reducers/reducer_weather.js

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
  console.log('Action received', action);
  return state;
}
```

src/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import WeatherReducer from './reducer_weather'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

What I want is that in reducer_weather I may get the response object, not a pending promise.

Comment: Probably not a good idea saving promises to state. They are not immutable.

Comment: Actually I'm learning react and redux, this code was write for me however based in a udemy course. I just tried reproduce the course, but I came across this mistake. The instructor did write this code and it worked for him.

Comment: It's incredibile.. I'm doing the exact same course on udemy and I'm stuck on the same spot. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should use then on get. like

```
axios.get(url).then((data) => {console.log(data)})
```

Comment: @LucasPeixoto I think it is saying you don’t have api keys. Please create them and post here what you get.